# How can I print the '<' symbol in the PDF generated through Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am trying to print the contents of a field in the PDF generated through Jasper report. The content of the text field is something like <=>I"< . When the PDF is downloaded '<' is getting omitted and the rest of the contents are getting printed. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "<" with `&lt;` and it will work.
When you want to print "<=>" you have to give 
`&lt;=&gt;` to the printer.